# Web Scrape google search pop-up results or www.prokabaddi.com

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the results after searching for 'Jaipur Pink Panthers' on google or directly visiting the prokabaddi website. Target is to scrape the table which pops up when you click on any match providing the total score spread for the entire match.

I have tried using beautiful soup and selenium but I endup reading nothing with the div class values. Any help in this regard is highly appreciable.

[image: Area to scrape is the pop-up here]

What I have tried as of now is as follows: [PS: I am absolutely new to Python]:

Attempt1:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium  import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.prokabaddi.com/stats/0-102-total-points-statistics')
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"lxml")
for item in soup.select('.sipk-lb-playerName'):
    [elem.extract() for elem in soup("span")]
    print(item.text)
driver.quit()
```

Attempt2:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


page = requests.get('https://www.prokabaddi.com/stats/0-102-total-points-statistics')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

name_list = soup.find(class_='.sipk-lb-playerName')
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post the attempt you made, and the error you encountered? Right now, you're asking someone to do it for you

Comment: yes. Please see the edited question now. Thanks :)

Comment: I mean the code you wrote and any stack traces it threw when it didn't work

Comment: None output in both cases... although the page is read fine

Comment: You should print out the values of `[elem.extract() for elem in soup("span")]` and `soup.find(class_='.sipk-lb-playerName')`

Comment: None is the output in both cases..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Little Background

Websites such as these, are made in such a manner to make the user's life easy by sending only the content that is *just required* by you at that point in time. 
As you move around the website and click on something, the remaining data is sent back to you. So, it basically works like a demand based interaction between you and the server.

## What is the issue in your code?

In your first approach, you are getting an empty **div** list even though you are able to see that element in the html source. The reason is you clicked on **Player** tab on the web-page and then it got listed there. It generated the new html content at that point of time and hence you see it.

## How to do it?

You need to simulate *clicking* of that button before sending the html source to BeautifulSoup. So, first find that button by using find_element_by_id() method. Then, *click* it.

```
element = driver.find_element_by_id('player_Btn')
element.click()
```

Now, you have the updated html source in your driver object. Just send this to BeautifulSoup constructor.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)
```

You do not need an lxml parser for this. Now, you can look for the specific class and get all the names (which I have done here).

```
soup.findAll('div',attrs={'class':'sipk-lb-playerName'})
```

Voila! You can store the returned list and get only the names formatted as you want.